# Angular2 response not mapping to TypeScript object

Tags: asp.net, angular, typescript, asp.net-web-api

I'm struggling to figure out why the response I get from my API isn't mapping to an object that I have in typescript.

Here's the function in my service that calls the API:

```
register(user: IUser): Observable<IUser> {
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    var options = new RequestOptions({
        headers: headers,
        url: this._registerUrl,
        body: JSON.stringify(user)
    });

    return this._http.post(this._registerUrl, { user }, options)
        .map((res: Response) => res.json() as IUser)
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

This is the function that calls the service:

```
register(): void {
    let user: IUser = {
        email: this.email,
        username: this.username,
        password: this.password
    }

    this._userService.register(user)
        .subscribe(result => {
            debugger;
            if(result.errorCode > 0)
                this.handleError(result.errorCode);
            else {
                localStorage.setItem('userId', result.userId.toString());
                localStorage.setItem('username', result.username.toString());
                localStorage.setItem('email', result.email.toString());
            }
        });
}
```

The object that I am returning from the API matches the object that I have in the frontend. It is returning the data and I can see it in the body of my response. All of the data is right, but it's in the body and is not turning it into an IUser object.

Does anybody have any ideas? Thanks.

**EDIT**

This is what the response object looks like when it comes back from the service.

[image]

Comment: what does the variable result look like in the subscribe()?

Comment: add "any" when you subscribe to your service: this._userService.register(user).subscribe((result:any) => {..}. But, why do you not use HttpClient ? http is "depreciated"

Comment: Can you try this code:  .map((res: Response) => <IUser>res.json())

Comment: I tried that but it did the same thing. I attached an image of what the object looks like when it comes back from the service.